# Stdin, stdout and stderr of asynchronously created Node.js child process

Tags: javascript, node.js

What's the correct way in Node.js to create child process asynchronously so that it's stdin, stdout and stderr are same as parent's. Should I use child_process.exec() or child_process.spawn(). Node.js version is 6.10.
Also, I kill the parent process soon after creating child process, so e.g. stdout cannot be printed with any callback function.